# Restore entire Hybrid-Environment

Tags: 2016, development-enviroment, hybrid

I currently build a testing environment which should have Office365 Hybrid features enabled (AppLauncher, Search, OneDrive, TeamSites).

This environment will be kept on a specific state by resetting Hyper-V Snapshots every weekend. I know, it's not recommended [(1)](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/sambetts/2015/08/24/virtual-machine-snapshots-for-sharepoint/) [(2)](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh295699.aspx) . But it's OK for this non-productive setup.

Has anyone done this before with a hybrid integrated SharePoint 2016? I am a little afraid that things break in O365 if a SharePoint-System "from the past" establishes connections to O365.

Any advice is appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

technically it should be fine. What is on prem stays on prem. Whats in the cloud stays in the cloud. So if you need to preform a disaster recovery on your prem then it should be fine and same goes with the connectors to 365 considering they were the same when you did the connection and dont change (Federated Delegation stays the same).

Saying this you should technically have a proper disaster recovery in place that overcomes this issue by setting out an azure disaster recovery to keep your environment and documentation safe and have virtually no down time.

having it on azure its almost a carbon copy of your prem but stored on azure and only spun up time to time for updates/backups to mitigate costs.

Microsoft go into depth on this very subject in "SharePoint recovery farm in Azure"

https://technet.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/dn635313.aspx